# mongoose localhost:8080 to custom name

Tags: mongoose-web-server

I am trying to use mongoose web server. I installed it, works fine. I could be able to view my index page as localhost:8080. I want want to change it to, myfile.localhost/ How can i change it?

I tried the following, but it isn't working.

I added the following line in C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts

```
 127.0.0.1     myfile.localhost (not working)
 127.0.0.1:8080     myfile.localhost (not working)
 8080 myfile.localhost (not working)
```

How can i fix it?

Comment: You are using NodeJS with mongoose?

Comment: @DeveshKumar no. I just installed mongoose in my file folder. Run mongoose then start browser. By the way, node.js is already installed in my computer. I don't know does it have anything to do with this. I haven't useed node.js.

Comment: Its NodeJS that is running at 8080 and not the mongoose. Mongodb runs at port 27017. Try uninstalling Node and you will find that its Node basically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working,

```
127.0.0.1       myfile.localhost
localhost       myfile.localhost
```

8080 port is already in use. So made mongoose use port 80. (In mongoose setting., set listening ports to 80)

Problem solved!!!